# TypeError: object function can't be used in await expression

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

> I have created an async function called `add_reaction_tasks` which maps specific function to dictionary keys. This function returns the dictionary to a variable called `tasks` which is located in the event `on_raw_reaction_add`.

The first issue is that `tasks = await add_reaction_tasks()` raises the following error: `line 343, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs)`.

The second one is when I try to access the dictionary, denoted by `tasks`, with the key `which_trigger` and the argument `payload`, the following error is raised:

`'1' : await add_rules_messages_tasks, TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression`.

I have made sure that `await` is used where possible. Besides that, I am not sure what else I have to get done, to make this code work.

The code snippets:

**1) the functions used in add_reaction_tasks**

```py
def display_messages_error(payload = discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
                            ...
async def add_rules_messages_tasks(payload = discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
                            ...
async def add_years_messages_tasks(payload = discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
                            ...
async def add_programming_languages(payload = discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
                            ...
```

**2) add_reaction_tasks function**

```py
async def add_reaction_tasks():
    add_tasks = {
                    '0' : display_messages_error,
                    '1' : await add_rules_messages_tasks,
                    '2' : await add_years_messages_tasks,
                    '3' : await add_programming_languages
                }
    
    return add_tasks
```

**3) on_raw_reaction_add event**

```py
@bot.event
@commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload : discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    role  = None
    guild = None
    # if the guild is server_name
    if payload.guild_id == server_id:
        guild = find(lambda g : g.id == server_id, bot.guilds)
    
    member = get(guild.members, id = payload.user_id)

    if not guild: return
    if not member: return

    which_trigger = 0 # 0 stands for invalid message id (should trigger display_message_error function)
    try:
        which_trigger = str(all_role_reaction_ids[str(payload.message_id)]) # <= looks weird, but works
        #print(f'\nwhich_trigger = {which_trigger}\n')
    except KeyError as err:
        print(f'KeyError: {err}')
        print('Invalid role-reaction message id')
        return

    tasks = await add_reaction_tasks()  # <= first error
    
    await tasks[which_trigger](payload) # <= second error

    return
```

Comment: ``async def`` functions are *constructors for* awaitables. ``await add_rules_messages_tasks()`` should work.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This what I had written before the code on this post, but it would just execute ALL the functions in the dictionary, despite providing a key that would call ONLY a certain one.

Comment: Well, yes, that is what ``await`` does – run a coroutine. Why do you use ``await`` when you do not intend to await the coroutine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the last three functions in the dictionary are asychronous, removing the `await` before them, makes them function as normal and no errors are raised.

However, how can they be asychronously run since the `await` keyword is not used before them?

**working code**

```py
async def add_reaction_tasks():
    add_tasks = {
                    '0' : display_messages_error,
                    '1' : add_rules_messages_tasks,
                    '2' : add_years_messages_tasks,
                    '3' : add_programming_languages
                }
    
    return add_tasks
```

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: @Black Yes; it solved my problem. To this day I still don't know how it works, but it works.